# Heroku / Am I forced to implement Workers Dynos in this case?

Tags: events, heroku, akka, playframework-2.2

I own a Play 2.2 application.

I'm about to implement an [Akka EventBus](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.4/scala/event-bus.html) capable of managing my various Domain Events inside my app.
The workflow would be:

- At application startup (`Global.scala`), an Akka Actor is scheduled periodically, retrieving current unpublished events from database.
- Then this scheduled actor would publish those events on the Akka EventBus.
- Various specific subscribing actors would then handle concerned events.

The important point is: I also own 2 **Web** Dynos on Heroku , each one running the app so.

Therefore, two drawbacks:

- Akka EventBus are strictly working on their own JVM (duplication of EventBus proportional to number of dynos).
- One application startup for each dyno among `n`, involving the presence of `n` event retrievers (scheduled actor as explained above).

Both typical unwished scenarios would be either:

- `Event1` is published multiple times (since one application startup by dyno)
- Even when `Event1` is published the first time, it might be handled several times by each `EventBus` present on each Dyno.

How to deal with this case?

**Am I forced to create a Worker Dyno, containing the EventBus + the event handlers or an easier solution may exist?**

Comment: I found this: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.4/common/cluster.html

Comment: http://pt.slideshare.net/developerforce/df121253-patterson (page 56): it seems that Akka Clustering is not possible when dealing with Heroku.